# How to match partial url in toHaveBeenCalledWith in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm testing the url by matching some part of it by using `toHaveBeenCalledWith` and the parameter should be without `null/`.

```
expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining(['/home']));
```

After I tried the command above, I got this error:

```
Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ <jasmine.objectContaining([ '/home' ])> ] but actual calls were [ [ 'null/home' ] ].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need setup your testing with either `RouterTestingModule` but that would require from you testing result of navigation instead of checking navigate arguments used.

Instead, you can have something like this:

```
class RouterMock {
  navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Router,
      useClass: RouterMock 
    },
    ...
  ]
});
```

You can check spy last called arguments something like this:

```
it('should...', inject([Router], (router: RouterMock) => {
  // ... setup test
  expect(router.navigate.calls.mostRecent().args).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(['/home'])); 
}))
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-ipxa1c)

Comment: I can't use mostRecentCall.

Comment: why it should be spy how are you spying on that method?
Or you are not using proper type for that spied router

Comment: I'm using spyOn(router, 'navigate'); and it work fine if I use expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['null/home']);

Comment: `jasmine.objectContaining` is ment to be used with `toEqual` not `toHaveBeenCalledWith` if you want to use it with spies you need to refer to `mostRecentCall` or other params added by spying mechanism

Comment: Is it possible if I use other command with toHaveBeenCalledWith to verify the url?

Comment: `toHaveBeenCalledWith` is just shortcut to get to `mostRecentCall.args` why cant you use it as in example above?

Comment: it shows me error:
Property 'mostRecentCall' does not exist on type '(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) => Promise<boolean>'.

Comment: ok that means that in this place in code typescript is not recognizing `navigate` as a spy and you cast it properly i will add details how to do that in answer

Comment: I got `error TS2345: Argument of type '(router: RouterMock) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ImplementationCallback'.
  Type '(router: RouterMock) => void' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<any>'.
error TS2339: Property 'mostRecentCall' does not exist on type 'Spy'.`

Comment: thought shortcut you need to use `inject([Router], ` updated answer

Comment: `mostRecentCall` still doesn't work.  `error TS2339: Property 'mostRecentCall' does not exist on type 'Spy'.`

Comment: sorry about that long time since i last used it fixed answer and here is working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-ipxa1c